# How can I save jenkins output to file

Tags: jenkins

Is anyone able to provide a way to save the jenkins output to a file that can be uploaded to s3 using shell commands and without the post-build plugin?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You might like to take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on how to help people help you. The biggest thing from all of that is that you will get far more useful responses if you show what you've already tried, and ask _specific_ questions to help you solve individual problems.

Comment: What do you mean by output? The Console Output or the Output Artifact?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Curl command to get the console output to a text file and then upload the file to your nexus, in the below example ,in place of last build you can specify the specific build number for which you want the console output.

> curl -L http://path-for-jenkins-JOB/lastBuild/consoleText > consoleText.txt